# checking which tab is selected from another form

Tags: c#, tabcontrol

From the original form form1, I can call this easily

```
this.tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text
```

But from form2, I cannot find equivalent method

```
(form1.Controls["tableLayoutPanel1"].Controls["tabControl1"] as TabControl)
```

does not have the SelectedTab method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the modifier on the TabControl's field `Public`, then you will be able to reference the tab control directly via the field with a reference to Form2.

It will look something like this after you have made the field public.

```
Form1 frm1 = <A reference to Form1 that you passed in to Form2 somehow>
frm1.TabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = "Changed Text!";
```

Comment: Sorry, I got the form names reversed.